# Asp.net mvc controls and html helpers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, controls

Apparently some vendors (like Telerik) are working on versions of their controls that do not rely on postback behavior to work.

As in the latest release of Asp.net MVC RC also code behind files tend to fade away for views, what would the best way for vendors to encapsulate UI rendering (control tags, html helpers) and control behavior?

Do you think that would be better for vendors to base their controls JavaScript dependency on framework like Jquery and extend that with classic Jquery plugins ?

As now we can send view data to the controllers in many ways should control vendors share some kind of convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at FluentHtml in [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) discussed [here](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/).